# Get an arbitrary key/item from a map

Tags: dictionary, go

I am new to Go and now I want to get an arbitrary item from a map; what's the idiomatic way to do that? I can only think of something like this:

```
func get_some_key(m map[int]int) int {
    for k := range m {
        return k
    }
    return 0
}
```

The reason I want that is I am using a map to maintain a set of jobs, and with a map I can get a pending job or remove a finished job in O(1). I guess this should be a common requirement but it's not obvious how to do it in Go.

Comment: Do you know the value of the key you are trying to get or set or are you trying to find a random key or some key you don't know in advance?

Comment: Are you looking for the key that has a particular value? If you're just looking for the value associated with a key it's simply `m[i]`.

Comment: Your approach looks good. If the map can be concurrently accessed by two goroutines, guard the retrieve/delete operation with a `sync.Mutex` so two goroutines don't grab the same job (and because maps are, for speed's sake, not natively thread-safe).

Comment: @dethtron5000 I don't need random key or sth, I just need to give me a  key for any element in the map if there are any

Comment: @twotwotwo Yep, I saw that from the [maps in action](http://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) article, and to be clear, I am using a sync.RWMutex.

Answer (score 23):

Whether getting an arbitrary key from a hash table is a common requirement may be discussed. Other language map implementations often lack this feature (eg. [Dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028136/random-entry-from-dictionary) )

However, your solution is probably the fastest one, but you will be left with a pseudo-random algorithm that you do not control. And while the current implementation uses a pseudo-random algorithm, the [Go Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) doesn't give you any assurance it will actually be random, only that it is not guaranteed to be predictable:

> The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next.

If you want more control of the randomization, you can also in parallel keep an updated slice of values (or keys) contained in the map, using the randomization of your choice (`math/rand` or `crypto/rand` for more extreme cases) to get the value stored at an index, selected randomly, in the slice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my comment above, I don't need any control of randomization, I just want a way that "just give me an element from the map" if there are any.

Comment: @chuchao333 Then your solution is good. Another similar way is `var k, v int; for k, v = range m { break }` if you want to do it inline. And to make sure you got a value, you can do: `var k, v int; var ok bool; for k, v = range m { ok = true; break }`

Comment: What do you mean by "get an index from the slice" in your last sentence?

Comment: @jochen: Maybe poor choice of words. I mean getting the value stored at a specific index in a slice. Eg.:  `slice[rand.Intn(len(slice))]`

Comment: @ANisus: But the question was about maps, not slices?  And I can't see an easy way to get a slice of all keys or similar.

Comment: @jochen: Yes. Question is about maps. But maps doesn't allow you to select an item i in an O(1) fashion. So, I also suggested a work-around solution having both a map and a slice. Works best in cases where deletions from the map is not required, or else deletion will be an O(n) operation as you also need to iterate over the slice.

Comment: C# has this feature: `dict.First()` It's not implemented in the Dictonary but in Linq, but it does exactly what is asked here.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a more generic version, although it may be less efficient:

```
    keys := reflect.ValueOf(mapI).MapKeys()
    return keys[rand.Intn(len(keys))].Interface()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0uvpJ0diG4e

Comment: It runs about 5 times slower than the method Xeoncross suggested. (Although I like this version because it's much simpler.) I made a test code here: https://play.golang.org/p/L2z5kGJ7WsW

Comment: This is even more terrible!  It's O(N) runtime and memory!

Answer (score 8):

Here you go.

Concurrent safe and O(1)

This is a wrapper for a map that adds "random" methods.

Example usage:

```go
package main

func main() {
    s := NewRandMap[string, string]()

    s.Add("myKey", "Item1")
    s.Add("myKey2", "Item2")
    s.Add("myKey3", "Item3")

    randomItem, _ := s.Random()

    fmt.Println(randomItem)
}
```

Data Structure:

```go
type RandMap[K comparable, V any] struct {
    m sync.RWMutex

    // Where the objects you care about are stored.
    container map[K]V

    // A slice of the map keys used in the map above. We put them in a slice
    // so that we can get a random key by choosing a random index.
    keys []K

    // We store the index of each key, so that when we remove an item, we can
    // quickly remove it from the slice above.
    sliceKeyIndex map[K]int
}

func NewRandMap[K comparable, V any]() *RandMap[K, V] {
    return &RandMap[K, V]{
        container:     make(map[K]V),
        sliceKeyIndex: make(map[K]int),
    }
}

func (s *RandMap[K, V]) Add(key K, item V) {
    s.m.Lock()
    defer s.m.Unlock()

    // store object in map
    s.container[key] = item

    // add map key to slice of map keys
    s.keys = append(s.keys, key)

    // store the index of the map key
    index := len(s.keys) - 1
    s.sliceKeyIndex[key] = index
}

func (s *RandMap[K, V]) Get(key K) (val V, ok bool) {
    s.m.RLock()
    defer s.m.RUnlock()

    item, ok := s.container[key]
    if !ok {
        return *new(V), false
    }

    return item, true
}

func (s *RandMap[K, V]) Remove(key K) {
    s.m.Lock()
    defer s.m.Unlock()

    s.remove(key)
}

// caller is responsible for locking
func (s *RandMap[K, V]) remove(key K) {
    // get index in key slice for key
    index, exists := s.sliceKeyIndex[key]
    if !exists {
        // item does not exist
        return
    }

    delete(s.sliceKeyIndex, key)

    wasLastIndex := len(s.keys)-1 == index

    // remove key from slice of keys
    s.keys[index] = s.keys[len(s.keys)-1]
    s.keys = s.keys[:len(s.keys)-1]

    // we just swapped the last element to another position.
    // so we need to update it's index (if it was not in last position)
    if !wasLastIndex {
        otherKey := s.keys[index]
        s.sliceKeyIndex[otherKey] = index
    }

    // remove object from map
    delete(s.container, key)
}

func (s *RandMap[K, V]) Random() (val V, ok bool) {
    s.m.RLock()
    defer s.m.RUnlock()

    if len(s.keys) == 0 {
        return *new(V), false
    }

    randomIndex := rand.Intn(len(s.keys))
    key := s.keys[randomIndex]

    item := s.container[key]

    return item, true
}

func (s *RandMap[K, V]) PopRandom() (val V, ok bool) {
    s.m.Lock()
    defer s.m.Unlock()

    if len(s.container) == 0 {
        return *new(V), false
    }

    randomIndex := rand.Intn(len(s.keys))
    key := s.keys[randomIndex]

    item, ok := s.container[key]
    if !ok {
        return *new(V), false
    }

    s.remove(key)

    return item, true
}

func (s *RandMap[K, V]) Len() int {
    s.m.RLock()
    defer s.m.RUnlock()

    return len(s.container)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a faster way I found to do this :

In my test, I created the following function

```
type ItemType interface{}

func getMapItemRandKey(m map[string]ItemType) string {
    return reflect.ValueOf(m).MapKeys()[0].String()
}
```

The key to each map is in the following format:

```
b := new(big.Int)
rbytes := (some random function to generate cryptographically safe random bytes)
b.SetBytes(rbytes)

key := b.String()
m := map[string]ItemType
m[key] = &ItemType{}
```

As a test, I'm getting the first key from my value as I request all keys but there is only one (... MapKeys()[0]).

This is super fast and can be adapted to any kind of map very easily.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the map only had one key which I needed to extract so for that you can do:

```golang
    var key string
    var val string
    for k, v := range myMap {
        key = k
        val = v
        break
    }
```

For multiple keys you could do something like,

```golang
func split_map(myMap map[string]string, idx int) (string[], string[]) {
    keys := make([]string, len(myMap))
    values := make([]string, len(myMap))
    count := 0
    for k, v := range myMap {
        keys[count] = k
        values[count] = v
        count = count + 1
    }
    return keys, values
}
```

While for accessing ith element,

```golang
func get_ith(myMap map[string]string, idx int) (string, string) {
    count := 0
    for k, v := range myMap {
        if idx == count {
            return k, v
        }
        count = count + 1
    }
    return "", ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is a array, which is easy to access randomly, especially
the container is random read heavy but changed infrequently.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually not a good idea to force an API on a data-structure that doesn't intrinsically support it. At best it will be slow, hacky, hard-to-test, hard-to-debug and unstable. Go's `map` natively supports `upsert`, `get`, `delete`, and `length` but not `GetRandom`.

Of the two concrete solutions mentioned here

- iterating over a range and choosing the first one does not guarantee a random item will be chosen or enable any control over the degree of randomness (ie uniform, gaussian, and seeding)
- reflection is hacky, slow and requires additional memory proportional to the size of the map

The other solutions talk about using additional data structures to help the map support this operation. This is what I think makes the most sense

```
type RandomizedSet interface {
    Delete(key int) // O(1)
    Get(key int) int // O(1)
    GetRandomKey() int // O(1)
    Len() int // O(1)
    Upsert(key int, val int) // O(1)
}

type randomizedset struct {
    h map[int]int // map key to its index in the slice
    indexes []int // each index in the slice contains the value
    source rand.Source // rng for testability, seeding, and distribution
}

func New(source rand.Source) RandomizedSet {
    return &randomizedset{
        h: make(map[int]int, 0),
        indexes: make([]int, 0),
        source: source,
    }
}

// helper to accomodate Delete operation
func (r *randomizedset) swap(i, j int) {
    r.indexes[i], r.indexes[j] = r.indexes[j], r.indexes[i]
    r.h[r.indexes[i]] = i
    r.h[r.indexes[j]] = j
}

// remainder of implementations here
```

Answer (score -4):

As a "global" solution, as I am a big fan of elasticsearch, you could use another map/array to store your data, to build a kind of an inverted dictionary.