# How to get a case to reply with a case previously added in a switch in C#?

Tags: c#, case

I have a question about switches in C#. I have a basic switch, three cases and a default, as you can see here:

```
string firstSwitch = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
switch (firstSwitch)
{ 
    case "goodbye":
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, Goodbye");
        break;

    case "gandalf":
        Console.WriteLine("YOU SHALL NOT PASS!");
        break;

    case "skyrim":
        Console.WriteLine("I used to be an adventurer like you, then I took an arrow to the knee.");
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("The Force is strong with this one.");
        break;
```

Now I want to add another case that will respond with a random case output that was previously added. For example:

```
case "giveRandom":
    //Code that returns the value for Case 0, case 1, or case 2,//
    break;
```

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: Just use a list of strings and pick a random one out of that list? Or use Dictionary.

Comment: I don't thing it is possible without using some dirty hacks. It is possible but you should not do it this way. Consider using some Strategy pattern with a list of reads

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. What exactly should happen in `case giveRandom` ?

Comment: @JPVenson It is possible using `goto case`, but I guess many people might consider the use of `goto` even within a `switch` to be a "dirty hack".

Answer (score 3):

Put all of your cases in a dictionary, and use this one in your switch statements:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
     new { "goodbye", "Hello, Goodbye" },
     new { "gandalf", "YOU SHALL NOT PASS!" },
     // etc
    new { "default", "The Force is strong with this one."}
};

string firstSwitch = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
switch (firstSwitch)
{ 
    case "goodbye":
        Console.WriteLine(dict["goodbye"]);
        break;

    case "gandalf":
        Console.WriteLine(dict["gandalf"]);
        break;

    case "giveRandom":
        // choose a random element in dict and display it
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine(dict["default"]);
        break;
}
```

**For the random switch, you just take a random element out of the dictionary as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028136/random-entry-from-dictionary).**

In fact, you can maybe even reduce the number of switches like:

```
switch (firstSwitch)
{             
   case "giveRandom":
        // choose a random element in dict and display it
        break;

    default:
        if (dict.ContainsKey(firstSwitch))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dict[firstSwitch]);
        }
        else
        {
             Console.WriteLine(dict["default"]);
        }
        break;
}
```

And as stated in the comments below, maybe you don't even need a switch (a simple if-then may suffice), but it depends on the logic that is involved.

```
if (firstSwitch == "giveRandom")
{
    // choose a random element in dict and display it
} 
else
{
     if (dict.ContainsKey(firstSwitch))
     {
          Console.WriteLine(dict[firstSwitch]);
     }
     else
     {
          Console.WriteLine(dict["default"]);
     }
}
```

And finally, also think about case sensitivity when comparing strings.

Comment: And how do you propose to pick a random element from the dictionary?

Comment: @L-Three there is only one case statement for the last piece of code, so do you really need a switch? if-else would be more than enough

Comment: @Jim: see the link to pick a random item from the dictionary

Comment: @CarbineCoder: I don't know the use case in detail, but it may very well be the case that switch is overkill. But hard to tell, there may be other logic involved.

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax that will do what you want directly (especially since `case` is deterministic so there's no way to execute a "random" case), but what you want should be doable by thinking about it a different way.  One way would be to put your cases in a `List<string>` and if `giveRandom` is selected then pick a string at random:

```
List<string> cases = new List<string> {"goodbye","gandalf","skyrim"};
string firstSwitch = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

if(firstSwitch == "giveRandom")
{
    // if this method will be called in a tight loop 
    // then make rand a field of the class instead
    Random rand = new Random();

    // pick a case at random
    firstSwitch = cases[rand.Next(0, cases.Count)];
}

switch (firstSwitch)
{ 
    case "goodbye":
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, Goodbye");
        break;

    case "gandalf":
        Console.WriteLine("YOU SHALL NOT PASS!");
        break;

    case "skyrim":
        Console.WriteLine("I used to be an adventurer like you, then I took an arrow to the knee.");
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("The Force is strong with this one.");
        break;
}
```

Comment: You'll want to create that `Random` at class scope. Otherwise multiple calls in quick succession will result in the same "random" number being generated.

Comment: @JimMischel Agreed, which is why I added that comment in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) directly, and no `switch` statement:

```
readonly SortedDictionary<string, string> _nameLookup = new SortedDictionary<string, string>
{
    {"goodbye", "Hello, Goodbye"},
    {"gandalf", "YOU SHALL NOT PASS"},
    {"skyrim", "I used to be an adventurer . . ."},
    {"default", "The force is strong with this one."}
};
readonly Random _rand = new Random();
```

Then, in your function:

```
void foo()
{
    string firstSwitch = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    string result;
    if (firstSwitch == "chooserandom")
    {
        result = _nameLookup[_rand.Next(_nameLookup.Count)];
    }
    else if (!_nameLookup.TryGetValue(firstSwitch, out result))
    {
        result = _nameLookup["default"];
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Granted, `SortedDictionary` is slower at lookup than `Dictionary`, but in a user interface application like this or if the number of options isn't huge, you'll never notice the difference. And selecting a random element here is easier and faster than with `Dictionary`.

This approach can also work well if you want to do more than just output a string. If you wanted to do a lot of processing for each item, you could replace the value in the dictionary with a method name (or an anonymous function). For example:

```
readonly SortedDictionary<string, Action> _nameDispatch = new SortedDictionary<string, Action>
{
    {"gandalf", ProcessGandalf},
    {"skyrim", ProcessSkyrim},
    // etc.
}
```

Of course, you'd need to define the methods `ProcessGandalf`, `ProcessSkyrim`, etc.

You'd use the same logic as above, but rather than writing the result, you'd have:

```
Action result;
// logic here to get the proper result.
// And then call that function:
result();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the way to go

```
  string firstSwitch = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            const string goodbye = "Hello, Goodbye";
            const string gandalf = "YOU SHALL NOT PASS!";
            const string skyrim = "I used to be an adventurer like you, then I took an arrow to the knee.";
            const string otherWise = "The Force is strong with this one.";
            switch (firstSwitch)
            {
                case "goodbye":
                    Console.WriteLine(goodbye);
                    break;

                case "gandalf":
                    Console.WriteLine(gandalf);
                    break;

                case "skyrim":
                    Console.WriteLine(skyrim);
                    break;
                case "giveRandom":
                    var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                    dic[0] = goodbye;
                    dic[1] = gandalf;
                    dic[2] = skyrim;
                    var rnd = new Random();
                    Console.WriteLine(dic[rnd.Next(2, 0)]);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine(otherWise);
                    break;
            }
```